# Advanced C calculator

Tags: c, calculator, windows

I was asked to create an Advanced calculator in C, I call it advanced because it actually handles arithmetic rules.
It was mentioned that I don't need to handle code exceptions and that I should assume that the code has legal input.

It works as follows:

1. Enter a number and press enter
2. Enter an operator and press enter To
3. To finish user input you press X and then enter.

Again I mention this, I assume correct input was put in the program.

**calc.h**

```
#pragma once

/*Sort the equation, deal with multipliers/divisors then sub and add, load it all in one array then recalculate */

/* Includes ******************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
/* Macros ********************************************************************/

/* Types *********************************************************************/

/* Global Variables *********************************************************/

/* Function Declarations *****************************************************/

/*Accept the equation as input and sort*/
void sort(IN int *numbers, IN char *operators);

/*Return result based on operator*/
int getOp(IN int a, IN int b, IN char op);

/*Create equation*/
void createEqu(IN int *numbers, IN char *operators);

/*Prints the equation*/
void print(IN int *numbers, IN char *operators);

/*Calculate array sum*/
void calSum(IN int *sorted, IN int length);
```

**calc.c**

```
/* Includes ******************************************************************/
#include "calc.h"

/* Macros ********************************************************************/

/* Types *********************************************************************/

/* Public Function Definitions ***********************************************/

/* Global Variables **********************************************************/

/*Create equation*/
void createEqu(IN int *numbers, IN char *operators)
{
    /*Intialize equation creater, 0 get number, 1 get operator*/
    int currentOperation = -1;

    /*Iterate through the arrays*/
    int n = 0;
    int o = 0;

    /*While equation input was not ended by user*/
    while (currentOperation != 2)
    {
        /*Number or operator*/
        if (currentOperation == -1)
        {
            printf("Enter number\n");
            scanf(" %d", &numbers[n]);

            /*If operator is negative, turn number into negative*/
            if (o != 0 && operators[o - 1] == '-')
            {
                numbers[n] = getOp(numbers[n], NULL, operators[o - 1]);
            }
            n++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Enter operator\n");
            scanf(" %c", &operators[o]);
            o++;
        }

        currentOperation = currentOperation*-1;
        /*check if the last operator was X to terminate equation input*/
        if (operators[o - 1] == 'X')
        {
            currentOperation = 2;
        }
    }

    /*Each array is terminated with NULL so it would be easy to read through them*/

    operators[o-1] = NULL;
    numbers[n] = NULL;
}

/*Prints the equation*/
void print(IN int *numbers, IN char *operators)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (;operators[i] != NULL; i++)
        printf("%c", operators[i]);
}

/*Return result based on operator*/
int getOp(IN int a, IN int b, IN char op)
{
    if (op == '*')
        return a * b;

    if (op == '/')
        return a / b;

    if (op == '+')
        return a;

    if (op == '-')
        return -a;
}

/*Calculate array sum*/
void calSum(IN int *sorted, IN int length)
{
    int i = 0;
    int finalRes = 0;

    for (; i <= length; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", sorted[i]);
        finalRes += sorted[i];
    }

    printf("%d", finalRes);
}

/*Accept the equation as input and sort*/
void sort(IN int *numbers, IN char *operators)
{
    int sorted[256];

    /*Iterators of arrays*/
    int s = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int o = 0;

    /*While expression is not over*/
    while (operators[o] != NULL)
    {
        /*If operation is + or - then store integers in sorted array for later calculation*/
        if (operators[o] == '+' || operators[o] == '-')
        {
            /*Save both original numbers                                             */
            sorted[s] = numbers[n];
            sorted[s + 1] = numbers[n + 1];

            s++;
            n++;
            o++;
        }
        else
        {
            /*calculate mandatory expression result and store in next cell value*/
            numbers[n + 1] = getOp(numbers[n], numbers[n + 1], operators[o]);
            n++;
            o++;

            /*If last operation was mandatory by arithmetic rules (div or mul), and its the last operation store result in sorted array*/
            if (operators[o] == NULL)
            {
                sorted[s] = numbers[n];
            }
        }
    }

    calSum(sorted, s);
}

/* Private Function Definitions **********************************************/
```

**main.c**

```
/* Includes ******************************************************************/
#include "calc.h"

/* Function Definitions ******************************************************/
INT wmain(IN SIZE_T nArgc, IN PCWSTR *ppcwszArgv)
{
    int numbers[256];
    char equ[256];

    createEqu(&numbers, &equ);
    sort(numbers, equ);
    getch();

    /* Succeeded */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Clearly state and add the review goals.

Comment: Where is  `IN` defined?

Answer (score 2):

1. Poor use of `NULL`.  In `operators[o] != NULL`, `NULL` is a *null pointer constant* best used with *pointers*.  `operators[o]` is a `char`, not a pointer.  Suggest below:

   ```
   // while (operators[o] != NULL)
   while (operators[o])
   // or 
   while (operators[o] != '\0')
   ```
2. Similar problem with `NULL` below.  Do not use `NULL` to indicate the *null character*.

   ```
   // getOp(numbers[n], NULL, operators[o - 1]);
   getOp(numbers[n], '\0', operators[o - 1]);

   // numbers[n] = NULL;
   numbers[n] = '\0';
   ```
3. `void print(IN int *numbers, IN char *operators)` is strange in that it never uses `numbers`.  Certainly incorrect functionality.
4. Highly suspicious about the correctness of the value of `s` in `calSum(sorted, s);`.  Such terse variable loses clarity as to it role.

Minor

10. `" "` in `scanf(" %d", &numbers[n]);` serve no purpose.  Code can be simplified to `scanf("%d", &numbers[n]);` and retain the same functionality.
11. Code that does not exceed the presentation width is more clear and easier to re-view.  (Code should not need horizontal scroll bars.)
12. I'd expect `const` for pointer to data that is not modified by the code.  `const` better conveys code's intent and allows for select optimizations.

    ```
       // void print(IN int *numbers, IN char *operators)
       void print(const int *numbers, const char *operators)
    ```
13. The role of `IN` is not defined and remains unclear.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback!
IN indicates INPUT while OUT indicates OUTPUT, these are the conventions i had to use.

Comment: the space in the scanf invokes it to ignore the previous '\n'

Comment: @Potato The space if not needed to ignore the previous `'\n'`.  `scanf("%d", &numbers[n]);` will ignore leading white-space, even without a space in the format.  Hence, `" "` in `scanf(" %d", &numbers[n]);` serves no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Strange use of `currentOperation` in calc.c: it is a state variable. Its values should be states that should have been defined with `#defines`.

```
currentOperation = currentOperation*-1;
```

This changes the state from the initial state `-1` to the "work-in-progress" state `1` and later from state `1` to state `-1`. Why not use assignment to make it clear? For example:

```
#define STATE_0      -1
#define STATE_1       1
#define STATE_END     2
```

---

`getOp`: that is a strange name "get operator/operation" where it calaculates an experssion. Shouldn't `calc` or so be a better name?

Also, this function sees + and - as unary and / and * as binary. Where/how are binary + and - handled?